# getting YN0028 The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden. using yarn berry and heroku

Tags: heroku, yarnpkg, heroku-ci

I'm using yarn berry and heroku and consistently getting the error:

```
       ➤ YN0028: │ The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden.
```

Which suggests that my lockfile does not contain all my listed dependencies. In the yarn docs it says this is easily solved by running `yarn install` and pushing new lockfile to git. However I've tried this, tried with fresh node_modules, etc with no luck.

Has anyone else experienced this issue using yarn berry + heroku?

My repo is a monorepo using workspaces.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## How to silence the error. ⚠ You don't want this!

I was able to workaround by setting the env-var `YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS` to `false`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/9481?sort=old#discussioncomment-660412).

This is likely a bug in Yarn Berry. I've reported it here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2948

---

**UPD**: I have created a **fresh local clone of the repo** from GitHub, ran `yarn install` in it, and it did produce changes in `yarn.lock`. Committing those changes resolved the CI issue, so disabling `YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS` is no longer necessary for me.

The original local repo showed a clean `git status`, so I still believe it is a bug.

**UPD 2**: My problem was that one of the Yarn worspaces was checked into git as a git submodule (I have probably created it with a nested `.git/` folder and then deleted it). As a result, the workspace content, including a child `package.json` was not committed into the repo, it only existed in my local repo and not on the remote and CI.

After removing the git submodule and checking the workspace into the repo properly, the `YN0028` error stopped happening.

Comment: hello. where to put YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS, thank you

Comment: @AlainIb I have already replied to you here: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/9481#discussioncomment-1063987

Comment: yes i saw the email notification from github. thank you soo much. i will try it soon when i close the current task. have a nice day

Comment: This is approved answer, but we should reconsider applying it as a first solution. In many cases (like mine) there is reason why yarn.lock is being modified during build. This should be fixed, not silenced. Inconstiency in modules version may cause problems to your app.

Comment: @MichalS, the question says that running yarn install and committing does not fix the issue. In my case, running yarn install locally did not modify the lockfole, so there was nothing to fix.

Comment: @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus absolutely. In your case (or the case from the question) it is totally fine. For some of us, googling the problem the reason may be different. (for me it was yarn version difference local/build). Thus silencing it would be not best way forward. My solution was enforcing version eg. "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.21".

Comment: I added a huge warning against silencing the error.

Comment: `YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS=false yarn` might do it if you need this

Answer (score 10):

**If your ENV doesn't contain any CI variables:**

Then it could be your yarn config:

Run `yarn config get enableImmutableInstalls` and see if it's enabled.
(you can also check why it is enabled by running `yarn config --why` and looking for `enableImmutableInstalls`).

If it is `true`, then run `yarn config set -H enableImmutableInstalls false` to set the setting's value globally (or without the `-H` argument to set it only in your current project)

Answer (score 4):

In my situation, cleaning the yarn cache locally with a `yarn cache clean --all` then running `yarn install` made the changes on `yarn.lock` the CI saw.

Pushing the updated `yarn.lock` then fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same issue. I resolve dit by deleting my cache and then reinstalling the dependencies.

The `yarn.lock` file was then modified by the time the reinstall had completed.

I believe this may have been because I checked in the `cache` folder initially, and then reverted it. Not sure if this then caused a discrepancy between my local environment and the checked-in repo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we created a new branch to work on a new project (project B) in the same repo as the old project (project A). The issue was that I accidently ran `yarn install` in the old directory (project A) instead of the one for the new project (B). As part of the gitlab pipeline we install and test all projects. So when I pushed this new yarn.lock to the feature branch, gitlab was failing to build project A.

THE FIX: I reverted the changes made to yarn.lock of project A, committing only changes made to the directory of the new project (B).

Directory overview:

```
./parent/
|-- project A         (old - not touched on the new branch)
|   |-- yarn.lock     (I accidently edited this one with `yarn install`. I just had to revert the changes to fix the issue)
|-- project B         (new, being developed on this new branch)
    |-- yarn.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue and in my case it was a yarn version mismatch!

My local project had the yarn upgraded to berry a long time ago and the current version of yarn was `4.0.2`. My pipeline was seting the yarn version with the `yarn set version berry` command, installing the yarn `4.1.0`, changing some checksums on the `yarn.lock`.

I solved this upgrading yarn locally and fixing the yarn version on the pipeline so instead of `yarn set version berry` im using `yarn set version 4.1.0`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

I'm using gitlab ci and got the same error, below solution worked for me:

```html
build:
  stage: build
  image: node:18.12.1
  script: 
    - yarn set version 1.22.19
    - yarn install
```

Note: Kindly check the node and yarn version from your developer, It should be correct. I'm using node:18.12.1 and yarn 1.22.19. For more information please check below useful link:

https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/9481?sort=old#discussioncomment-1154692

Comment: As the question explicitly states that they're using Yarn Berry, I don't think reverting to a previous version would be a valid solution.