# Deploying monorepo project to vercel with yarn while ignoreing other projects in .vercelignore results in error YN0028

Tags: yarnpkg, vercel, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo with packages and apps that uses yarn 3.6.1. When I deploy the web app to Vercel I have to include the unrelated apps in `.vercelignore` since the website does not use them and it makes the deploy massive for now reason.

However this causes an issue where when `yarn install` runs on Vercel it doesn't have those other workspaces to worry about and it results in a different `yarn.lock`, throwing an error `YN0028: │ The lockfile would have been modified by this install, which is explicitly forbidden.`

How do I get around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67062308/getting-yn0028-the-lockfile-would-have-been-modified-by-this-install-which-is-e does this work?

Comment: @PrinceAgrawal No. That solution explicitly makes it change when using the `YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS` solution or, in the other solution there,  removing the other app completely from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own question! I revisited this and the best solution I came up with was to include the unrelated app folders but just ignore the large folders inside those app folders. For me my .vercelignore looks like:

apps/expo-app/ios
apps/expo-app/android